# load my user_login from database into my acf select field code

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

**I am trying to upload my user_login from database into acf select field, in var_dump my array result is working good, but nothing uploaded in my acf select field?**

**1. I added a custom field "ACF select field" in a product post.**

**2. I'm trying to load my options values from my database.**

**3. I used an array to get the user_login values from the database**

function.php

```
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=chef', 'my_acf_load_chef_field');
     function my_acf_load_chef_field( $field )
{   
    $user_fields = array( 'user_login');
    $argu = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'chef' , 'fields' => $user_fields ));
    $choices = $argu->get_results();
    $field = array();  
     if( is_array($choices) ) {
        $len = count($choices);
        for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            array_push($field, ($choices[$i]->user_login));
    }
   }
    // var_dump($field);
    // exit;
    return $field;
}
```

**this is the var_dump result**

```
array(5) { 
[0]=> string(5) "Ahmed" 
[1]=> string(5) "Khedr" 
[2]=> string(4) "meme" 
[3]=> string(5) "Menna" 
[4]=> string(7) "mustafa" } 

this is the array result that i want to load in acf field
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i found it**
**this is the new code**
thanks justkidding96

```
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=chef', 'my_acf_load_chef_field');

function my_acf_load_chef_field( $field )
{    
    $user_fields = array( 'user_login');
    $argu = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'chef' , 'fields' => $user_fields ));
    $choices = $argu->get_results();
    //$choices = get_field($field['choices'], $post->ID , false);
    $field['choices'] = array();  
     if( is_array($choices) ) {
        $len = count($choices);
        for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            array_push($field['choices'], ($choices[$i]->user_login));
    }
   }
    // var_dump($field['choices']);
    // exit;
    return $field;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your don’t assign your choices to the field. Try this code:

```
if (is_array($choices)) {
    // Clear the choices
    $field[‘choices’] = [];

    // Assign the data to the field
    foreach ($choices as $choice) {
       $field[‘choices’][$choice->user_login] = $choice->user_login;
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: Illegal offset type in D:\SEVER\SHARE\www\jeeraco\wp-content\themes\norebro\functions.php on line 135
array(1) { ["choices"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Try ‘$field[‘choices’] = $choices;’ instead of the foreach loop

Comment: thanks for your interest i done it with you help by added ['choices'] after the $field variable